# Show the clip-time in VLC-player, while playing

Tags: vlc

I'm recording some sports footage, and write down some notes, while the recording is going on.

I would like to be able to, as fast as possible, to link my comment to the passage on the video. I record it with a GoPro, so the 1,5 hour longs video gets chopped up to small pieces.

I thought it would be an idea, if VLC could display the actual time of when the footage was take, on screen. In the same manner of this (opening VLC from a command-line with that comment):

```
vlc.exe --sub-filter=marq{marquee=$T/$D" Volume:"$V,size=-2,color=16776960}:marq{marquee=Time:%H:%M:%S" Date:"%d/%m/%Y,color=16776960,size=-2,position=6}
```

That line just shows the current time. I wanted it for example to show something like this:

If the recording was started at `19:39:21`, - then three minutes and 7 seconds into the video, the counter should say `19:42:28`. Is that achievable somehow?